# Django: Access Class Method of Model via RelatedManager

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following setting:
    class Baguette(models.Model):
        # fields

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    # fields

class Topping(models.Model):
    # fields

    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
        # stuff

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PizzaTopping(models.Model):
    obj = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, related_name='topping_set')

class BaguetteTopping(models.Model):
    obj = models.ForeignKey(Baguette, related_name='topping_set')
```

I know, the way the relations are made is not perfect, but this is now the way it is.

My question is: Can I access `do_something` in a dynamic way via RelatedManager without knowing if there is `PizzaTopping` or `BaguetteTopping` behind it?

I have an instance `obj` of `Pizza` or `Baguette` (at this point I don't know if it is `Pizza` or `Baguette`). Now I want to call something like this:

```
obj.topping_set.__modelclass__.do_something()
```

Is there a way to do this without testing the class of `obj` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj.topping_set.model` will be your model class. So `obj.topping_set.model.do_something()`.